# How does data storage get calculated for Salesforce CMS Content Records?

Tags: community, salesforce-cms, storage

I'm looking for some information on how much storage is used by the different components of Salesforce CMS. E.g. for each Content Record, how much storage space is used? Is it always the same, or does it vary based on something like the length of the content, images included, or even Content Type being used?

I have assumed that it will not follow the same 2KB per record storage ratio as other data in Salesforce, but if someone can tell me with certainty that this is the case, and point me to the relevant documentation, that would be grand.

The reason why I need this information is because the free version of Salesforce CMS supports up to 500 Content records, but doesn't provide additional data storage. Therefore I'd like to calculate the average amount of data storage that will be used for a Content Record, to ensure that I will have enough storage available for 500 records.

Resources already explored:

- https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/cms/
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_managed_content_overview.htm&type=5
- https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/communities.pdf
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/cms_dev_customcontenttypes.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found anything that specifies the exact storage amounts for Content Records. But you could run some initial tests of your own by:

- Setting up a Content Record
- Navigating to Setup > Storage Usage
- Scrolling down to the Content Bodies storage value under the "File Storage Usage" header

The Content Bodies value encompasses Files and the body of Content Records, so you'll want to ensure you're in an "empty" org that is clear of documents before testing.

Note that storage value as your benchmark, then add a new Content Record; e.g. with the a longer or shorter body to test whether the body length changes how much storage is used up.

If you find that the storage usage varies based on body length of each Content record (my assumption is that this is the case solely because Content Record storage is shown under the "File Storage Usage" header), then you can run more scenarios on your own and/or submit a Salesforce Case asking exactly how it's calculated.